# Dynamic programming problem

Tags: probability, dynamic-programming

A man is in a room, with $n$ passages leading out. For passage $i$, $i = 1,...,n$, there is probability $p_i$ of escaping, $q_i$ of being killed and $r_i$ of returning to the room, where $p_i + q_i + r_i = 1$. In which order should the man try the passages so as to maximise his chances of eventual escape?

I am trying to formulate this as a dynamic programming problem, but am not sure how to associate costs with it. I am also not sure if I need to use discounting for the "death" scenario.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is known that the probabilities are independent for each passage, and $p_i,q_i,r_i$ are all known. Given these 3n numbers, how should you go about solving the problem?

Comment: So I just go for the passage with the smallest $q_i$ every time? But what if $p_i$ for this passage is also small, wouldn't I be better off going for a passage with a greater value of $p_i$?

Comment: I think an interchange argument works here; work out the probability of escaping for some generic order of caves, then switch two adjacent caves, and find some index to rank

Comment: Did you mean to suggest that he can't just keep trying the same passage over and over again?

Comment: The variety of solutions indicate that the problem isn't clear.  Are you saying that if I try passage $i$ repeatedly, different things might happen with the given probabilities?  Or are you saying that the $i$-th passage is one of three types, but you just don't know which type?  The frequentists and the Bayesians would like to know...

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two passages, your chance of escape is $p_a+r_ap_b$ or $p_b+r_bp_a$.
Use $r_a=1-p_a-q_a$, this is $p_a+p_b-q_ap_b-p_ap_b$ or $p_a+p_b-p_ap_b-q_bp_a$.
So choose passage $A$ if $q_ap_b<p_aq_b$, or $p_a/q_a>p_b/q_b$.
This means that you should choose in decreasing order of $p_i/q_i$.

Answer (score 0):

The outcomes of this process are strings of $P_i$, $Q_i$, $R_i$, where $P_i$ means escape through passage $i$, $Q_i$ means die through passage $i$, and $R_i$ means return through passage $i$. The string terminates as soon as we hit $P_i$ or $Q_i$.

So a typical outcome, if $n=4$, might look like $R_1 R_3 R_4 R_2 Q_2$. If we associate $P_i$ with $p_i$ and so on then, by independence, the probability of each outcome is simply the string interpreted as a product:
$$\Pr(R_1 R_3 R_4 R_2 Q_2) =r_1 r_3 r_4 r_2 q_2. $$

(It is also possible to have an infinite string of $r$'s, but if $r_i<1$ for each $i$ then the probability of these are all 0.)

Now let us ask all the ways we can escape in at most 2 moves. That's all the strings $P_i$ and all the strings $R_iP_j$. These pair up into the two escape outcomes of strategies 
$(i,j)$ where $(i,j)$ means first try the $i$th passage then try the $j$th passage.
Now the probability of escape with strategy $(i, j)$ is
$$\Pr(P_i)+\Pr(R_iP_j) = p_i + r_i p_j.
$$

By the same reasoning, the probability of escape with strategy $(i_1, i_2, i_3, i_4, \ldots)$
is 
$$
p_{i_1} + r_{i_1} p_{i_2} + r_{i_1} r_{i_2} p_{i_3} + r_{i_1} r_{i_2} r_{i_3} p_{i_4} +\cdots,
$$
an infinite series. So in general the problem seems a bit intractable to me.

If each passage can only be tried once then you need only consider $(1, 2, 3, \ldots, n)$ and all its permutations. A computer program could compute all those sums and select the maximum. However, as $n$ increases the number of such strategies ($n!$) increases very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Make best use of your resources. Or, in other words minimize cost. You only fail to escape if you die, but you have greater chance of dying if you fail to escape: because you must risk your life again.

Try that passage which has greatest positive difference between increase in probability of escape if going by another passage and increase in probability of death if going by another passage. Then try the passage with the next such greatest difference, and so on, assuming you can try every passage once. Or repeat the first passage if many tries are allowed.

This would maximize chance of escape. So this is an iterative solution in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Markov / Transition matrix approach to the question.

Each door has the following transition matrix:

$$M_i = \begin{array} {c|ccc}
               & \text{Room} & \text{Escaped} & \text{Dead} \\ \hline
   \text{Room} &     R_i     &     P_i        &    Q_i      \\
\text{Escaped} &  0 & 1 & 0 \\
   \text{Dead} &  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array} = 
\begin{bmatrix} T_i & F_i \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}$$

The steady state of each door is :

$$S_i = (I - T_i)^{-1}F_i = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{P_i}{1 - R_i} & \frac{Q_i}{1 - R_i} \end{bmatrix}$$

So the chance of escape if you repeatedly choose door $i$ is $\frac{P_i}{1 - R_i}$ and the chance of dying is $\frac{Q_i}{1 - R_i}$.

It is observable that $P_i + Q_i + R_i = 1$ implies $\frac{P_i}{1 - R_i} + \frac{Q_i}{1 - R_i} = 1$.